# ArrayList & Array methods

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm writing a simple code to show various details about a person. I've used arrays to create name.

When I try to run my code the location/ directory for name comes out as `[Ljava.lang.String;@1f32e575`.

My code runs results are:

```
Name
ii
jj
[Ljava.lang.String;@1f32e575 // code to remove
```

My code:

```
    public static String[] name() {

        System.out.println("Name");
        n = new String[]{ "ii", "jj" };
        for (int i = 0; i < n2.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(n[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You forgot to close the quotation on `hobby2 = new String[] { "ii, "jj" };` Also this code is very hard to read, please format this a bit better to make it easier to debug and remove any unnecessary code that isn't directly related to your problem.

Comment: The code in your question will not produce that output.  The output you have labelled as "code to remove" would be output if you called `println` on `n`.  But you don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, is your fixed code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Detail {
    private String name;
    private String nationality;
    private static String[] hobby2;

    public Detail() {

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name = "A";
    }

    public String getNationality() {
        return nationality = "abc";
    }

    public void setInfo(String name, String nationality) {
        this.name = name;
        this.nationality = nationality;
    }

    public static void setHobbies() {

        hobby2 = new String[] { "ii", "jj" };

        System.out.println("Hobbies");

        for (int i = 0; i < hobby2.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("\t" + hobby2[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void setWishes() {

        System.out.println("Wishes");

        ArrayList<String> allWishes = new ArrayList<String>();

        allWishes.add("aa");
        allWishes.add("bb");
        allWishes.add("cc");
        allWishes.add("dd");

        for (String i : allWishes) {
            System.out.println("\t" + i);
        }
    }

    public void displayDetail() {
        DOB d = new DOB();

        System.out.println("Name: " + getName());
        System.out.println("Nationality: " + getNationality());
        System.out.println("Date of birth: " + d.dateString(1, "Jan", 1000));
        setHobbies();
        setWishes();
    }

}

class DOB {

    public String dateString(int day, String month, int year) {
        String dob = (day + " " + month + ", " + year);
        return (dob);

    }
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyInfo my = new MyInfo();
        my.displayDetail();

    }

}
```

The very first value you don't want was the object ID, you simply can't return the values of an object. If you want to see the values then you have to override the `toString()` method.

The second value was visible just because you returned the list. If you were using `print()` inside your method then there was no need to return it.

Tips: You need to get a better understanding of getter and setter methods because you have messed up the entire concept in your code. Your blank constructor is not needed. Rather, you should initialize all the fields (class variables of **Detail** class) in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Remove System.out.println in displayDetail() method as below,

```
    setHobbies();
    setWishes();
```

Comment: And also the return the type and return statements must be removed.